# display all pdfs placed in raw folder in a listview in android?

Tags: android

I want to display all .pdf files placed in raw folder in a listview .when i click a button it should display list of pdf files.Actually i want to uploadselected pdfs in a list from my android app to Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();
String[] arrData = assetManager.list("pdfFolder");//name of your directory as assets/pdfFolder/abc.pdf
List<String> pdfList = new ArrayList<String>();
int size =  arrData.length();
for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
{
  if(arrData[i].contains(".pdf"))

  {
    pdfList.add(arrData[i]); 
   }
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, pdfList);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```